# How to implement ionic-stepper just like angular material stepper?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic-angular application, I want to the ionic stepper.

[Here is the ionic stepper example but it is given an error in the app.module.ts file (ionic-angular module not found).](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-stepper)

Comment: use the one provided in angular material
[https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview]

Answer (score 0):

Simply, we can use angular stepper in ionic framework. it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

replace 'ionic-angular' with '@ionic/angular'